# how to remove particular attribute name from a list type

Tags: jquery, html

how to remove a list type has a particular attribute name,am trying to remove a particular li having the attribute name from a dynamic varible. how to solve this

```
var Attribute = 2;
<ul>
<li name="1">as</li>
<li name="2">asd</li>
<li name="3">asdf</li>
</select>
$("ul li").each(function () {
if($(this).hasAttr("name",Attribute){
$(this).remove();
}
else{
alert("no attribute present");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this:

1. Looking up the `li`:

   ```
   var li = $('li[name="' + Attribute + '"]');
   ```

   Note the string concatenation. It produces a string like `li[name="2"]`. In your example, we don't need the `"` around the attribute value, but if it contained a space or some other characters, we would, so best to include them.

   That's a CSS selector. More about them [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).
2. Removing it with [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

   ```
   li.remove();
   ```

Those can be combined, of course:

```
$('li[name="' + Attribute + '"]').remove();
```

Live Example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    var Attribute = 2;
    $('li[name="' + Attribute + '"]').remove();
}, 800);
```

```html
<ul>
<li name="1">as</li>
<li name="2">asd</li>
<li name="3">asdf</li>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check attribute using `attr()`. `attr()` gives you attribute value of what you give.

```js
var Attribute = 2;

$("ul li").each(function () {

  if($(this).attr('name') == Attribute){
     $(this).remove();
   }
   else{
     //alert("no attribute present");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li name="1">as</li>
<li name="2">asd</li>
<li name="3">asdf</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with simple direct selector `$("ul").find('li[name="'+Attribute+'"]').remove()`

```js
var Attribute = 2;
$("ul").find('li[name="'+Attribute+'"]').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li name="1">as</li>
  <li name="2">asd</li>
  <li name="3">asdf</li>
</ul>
```